# Loop over column to verify condition and change cell values when need it with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[Pandas Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjbla.png), I would like to loop over the column named 'first' to verify if is an email or not, if is an email remove it and leave that cell blank.

I have try

```
for x in df['first']:
     if '.com' in x:
         x = ''
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What's your question? There's more than one problem with this code: 1) that's not how to verify an email address, 2) it doesn't change the cell value.

Comment: Start here: [How to check for valid email address?](/q/8022530/4518341)

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the `pandas` portion of this, since that's not exactly email verification.

Use `.map` with a `lambda` function for this. This is the preferred way to do what you are trying to do in pandas, instead of iterating.

```py
df['email'] = df['email'].map(lambda x: x if '.com' in x else '')
```

Comment: That was pretty close but in this case the code delete the cells I want to keep, I want to delete the emails on that column